# C# How to return a specific column from a database table using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a database with a table `person` that has columns `PersonID, firstName, lastName`.

I am trying to fill a combobox with all the first names from this table. This is what I have so far:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        dbSet dbContext = new dbSet();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           var names = dbContext.People.SqlQuery("Select FirstName FROM person").ToArray(); 
            dgMain.ItemsSource = names;
            dgMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

But this always gives an error

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'dbSet.Counselor1'. A member of the type, 'CounselorID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: You are saying you have a SQL table called Person and want to use the names from it, but are running a `Select FirstName FROM counselors`. Is that a typo? Sounds to me like it should be `Select FirstName FROM Person`.

Comment: Oops.  I was trying to simplify my tables to make it more understandable without having to explain too much.  Fixed the typo.

Comment: Cool, but the error is still happening right?

Comment: Another typo in the post. I do have the dbContext.People.  I'm just confused because when I do a "Select *" it will populate my datagrid but when I do a "select firstname" it throws an exeption.  I KNOW that firstname is a column in the table and querying it in the actual database works.

Comment: it sounds like the code is trying to box your query results into a Person/counselor object. Therefore when u change ur sql query to only select 1 column, it throws an error. Check ur var datatype, if i am right, it is of type Person [］. if so, u probably need to select all columns in your query and then extract the firstname after execution

Comment: If you seem to be using Entity Framework - why are you using raw SQL code?!?!?! The whole point of EF is to **avoid** having to write raw SQL.... just use `dbContext.People.Select(p => p.FirstName);` and that's it!è

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using Entity Framework - why are you using raw SQL?? The whole point of EF is to avoid having to write raw SQL!

Just use the "native" features of EF - Linq-to-Entities - to get your list of first names!

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var names = dbContext.People.Select(p => p.FirstName);

    dgMain.ItemsSource = names;
    dgMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

and you're done!